# How to combine Split mode with Octave Piano instrument on Yamaha keyboards?

Tags: piano, keyboard

I am trying to combine the Split feature with the Octave Piano instrument on my Yamaha PSR-E363*. I want to press a single key with my left hand to play an octave chord while my right hand operates as single notes.

First, I hit the Split button to activate it, then tap-and-hold to choose a split voice. I then select 162, the Octave Piano, but then the notes on the left-hand ring out as single notes.

However, if I choose the Octave Piano without using the Split feature, the keyboard produces octave chords as expected.

I am relatively new to the Yamaha keyboard, so I expect I don't fully understand how Split and Dual Voices work.

*My Yamaha is equivalent to the Yamaha YPT-360 and probably many other Yamaha models.

Comment: What sound are you choosing for the other side of the split? I've never been very good at the outsides of these keyboards, I used to work on the insides… but in general a split needs you to choose a voice for each half of the split. If you don't, I'm assuming it's choosing voice #1 for you… default piano. [Either that or the octave piano actually needs two voices to generate, rather than it being in the sample set as a dual, meaning you don't have enough voices to play three things at once.]

Comment: It's choosing Finger Bass for that voice. I suspect what I want is not possible. The Yamaha manual has a diagram showing that when you enter Split mode, the left side is for Split Voice only, and the right side is for the Main and Dual Voices.

Comment: Ah, OK. Yes, that sounds about right. Maybe someone will come along who understands the control surfaces of these keyboards better. To my shame, I used to work programming the insides of those keyboards [if not that specific model… I did it for a decade & much of what we did was for the top model each year, which was then split down by other programmers to the lower end models, so I don't even know which my work ended up in], but I never bothered to learn how they worked for the user. My bad ;)